# Why does "sbt run" fail with OutOfMemoryError while "activator run" works fine?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I can successfully start my application with **activator run** but simple **sbt run** ends either with OutOfMemoryError or sudden termination of the application.

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2"
```

If my understanding is right Activator should delegate all commands beside custom one's to SBT. Apparently, it seems that Activator does something more.

How can I find the difference? Are there any mandatory JVM settings that I should set before running my app with SBT?

My environment is Java 7, Windows 7 and SBT 0.13.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, there's no difference. Activator essentially just invokes sbt. It does a little bit more though, it includes some sbt plugins that provide the ui and the ability to create a new project from templates. It also invokes sbt with some more sensible default JVM settings than most vanilla sbt invoker scripts, including more memory.

How to set better defaults depends on which sbt invoker script you're using, and this may depend on how you installed sbt. But most scripts support an `SBT_OPTS` environment variable, put `-Xmx1024m` in that for example to give sbt a gig of heap space. You may also want to add `-XX:MaxPermSize=768m` if you're getting perm gen space out of memory errors.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I went through related part of the activator.bat script. Setting **-XX:MaxPermSize** in **SBT_OPTS** has solved my issue.